# Azure pipelines read file from resources repository

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am referencing a repository in my azure-pipelines template like this:

```
resources:
  repositories:

    - repository: MyRepo
      type: git
      name: MyRepoName
      ref: MyRepoRef
```

I would like to know if it is possible to read the content of a file that is inside the referenced repository, inside this repository is another yaml that is being executed in the pipeline.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If we use another repo in the pipeline, we could read the content of a file in the referenced repository. We could refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#inline-syntax-checkout) for more details

In my test, project name is `test`, the referenced repository is `test` and current repository is `sample`, then I read the content of file `pull_request_template.md`

YAML build definition:

```
trigger: none

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: test
    type: git
    name: test/test
    ref: master

steps:
#checkout referenced repository
  - checkout: test
#List SourcesDirectory files
  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: 'ls ''$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'''
#Read the contents of the file pull_request_template.md
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: 'Get-Content -Path $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\pull_request_template.md'
```

Result:

[image]